# What is the standard way to enable CTRL+arrow (alt+B and alt+F) in the non-GUI console?

Tags: debian, console, readline

I'm using "standard" just in case there's some obvious method, or this feature is part a larger issue that I'm not aware of (as in perhaps involving enabling related shortcuts and features). Otherwise I don't mind just adding my own shortcuts.

Comment: On what operating system?  FreeBSD?  TrueOS?  OpenBSD?  NetBSD? Illumos?  A Linux operating system? ...

Comment: I just updated the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your shell uses the `readline` library, here is what I have in my default `/etc/inputrc` file:

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

This file is only read if the `INPUTRC` environment variable is not set, and if you don't have any `.inputrc` file in your home directory.

Now, we must instruct the console to emit one of the `backward-word` strings when Ctrl-Left is pressed, and one of the `forward-word` strings when Ctrl-Right is pressed.

For this, we must add some special keyboard mappings to `/etc/console-setup/remap.inc`:

```
# Ctrl + Left arrows key (readline's backward-word)
control keycode 105 = F200
string F200 = "\033[5D"

# Ctrl + Right arrows key (readline's forward-word)
control keycode 106 = F201
string F201 = "\033[5C"
```

Here I have borrowed two keysyms `F200` and `F201` (picked up quasi randomly from the output of `dumpkeys --long-info`) in order to store the sequences expected by `readline`. `keycode 105` is the left arrow, and `keycode 106` is the right arrow (those keycodes were obtained with `dumpkeys` too).

Now, let's rebuild our new keymap :

```
setupcon --save-only
```

It should (re)create the file `/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz`. You can load it manually with the command:

```
loadkeys /etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz
```

Or, better, similarly to when your machine boots:

```
service console-setup start
```

UPDATE 2023

Current Debian releases use `/etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz` instead of `/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz`.

Comment: You have them (so do I), but do they work? In the **non-GUI** console? (That would be amazing.)

Comment: @argle have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @MrShunz Just test them in the ***kernel*** console and you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: @argle What i meant is that you asked if they work, as if you haven't tried them yourself. That said, I don't have a debian machine at hand, but on my ubuntu system they don't work on tty console (same `/etc/inputrc` though).

Comment: @MrShunz No, I haven't tried it myself (obviously). It's xhienne's machine and only he can try; that's why I needed to ask him :P. I could (and did) only try it on my machine (obviously; hence my SE question and note that I said I'd already had those very same configuration lines) and I found it amazing that (xhienne implied) it worked on his machine. By the way, try it on your ***non***-Debian machine and you'll see that it's not working either.

Comment: Well, as you already said.

Comment: Sorry @angle for my silence. You are right that my solution is not sufficient, I missed the fact that it is working for you **except** on the console. Indeed, it's not working for me either. My understanding, base on `dumpkeys` output, is that there is no character sequence defined for Ctrl+arrow. I'll try and come back with a solution shortly. Ping me if this is not the case, or if you have found the solution yourself.

Comment: @argle I have updated my answer with a solution that I have tested on my machine (I did not test the reboot though).

Comment: @xhienne Not working, unfortunately. The remap.inc additions seem to be fully ignored (the commands run fine; no error messages). By the way, the /etc/inputrc method does work, it's just that the console takes the `\e` literally (as the escape key, not as the control key). If I press escape and then the arrow key once in the console, the cursor moves one word away.  I tried with \C instead of \e and control still won't do anything.

Comment: @argle The ESC+arrow behaviour is normal. With readline, ESC is the `meta` key (see readline's manpage). I suspect the new keymap is not loaded. I have updated my answer to include a manual loading. Can you check 1. that the `cached.kmap.gz` file is indeed recreated, 2. that it contains the content of `remap.inc`, and 3. that the `loadkeys` command succeeds?

Comment: It WORKS! It wasn't the manual loading that made the difference. It seems the original `/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz` needs to be removed before using `setupcon --save-only`. I didn't understand your solution, by the way. How did you come up with the `F200` and `F201`?

Comment: @argle It's really weird that `setupcon` didn't succeed in overwriting the previous cache (I assume you are root). As for F200 and F201, those are (hopefully) empty slots, I just had to choose two keysyms from `dumpkeys -l` output. I could have used F77 and F29. I just used high enough numbers to avoid collisions with possible existing definitions on your side.

Comment: Yes, root. Otherwise I get `/etc/console-setup is not writable. No files will be saved there.` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer @xhienne. A few more infos for further readers: The key code for left/right *might* be 113/114 on some systems. Only some OS-es seem to be [off by 8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52949/103120). You can show keycodes with `xev`, find possible keysyms with `sudo dumpkeys -l` and keycodes in use with `xmodmap -pke` and print input codes emacs style (inputrc) with `ctrl+v keypress`.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux console, you can customize your keymap.  The place to start is with [`dumpkeys`](http://kbd-project.org/manpages/man1/dumpkeys.1.html).  That's the standard *approach*.  There's no applicable standard for Linux console *bindings*, but you can certainly imitate GUI (i.e., xterm as hinted by xhienne).

I don't see a duplicate, but these would be helpful:

- [What happens when Ctrl + Alt + F is pressed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63688/what-happens-when-ctrl-alt-fnum-is-pressed/63700#63700)
- [Binding additional keyboard shortcuts in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53808/binding-additional-keyboard-shortcuts-in-bash/53835#53835)

Comment: +1 for the help. I'll test it as soon as I get some time and I'll return with updates.

Comment: I did some more reading. It turns out I understood your solution; it was just unrelated to my question. I hope I'll make inputrc work and post the answer here soon.